# xdebug_debug_zval doesn't returns value and doesn't output something

Tags: xdebug

Can you help me?
I can't understand why xdebug_debug_zval doesn't works?
I try

```
$r =  5;
xdebug_debug_zval($r);
```

I call it in console:

```
php test.php
```

and it outputs nothing. Is I need to configure xdebug.ini? or php.ini?
Help me, please.

Answer (score 5):

The `xdebug_debug_zval` function requires the name of the variable to be passed to it, not the variable itself. In order to make it work you should correct your script:

```
$r = 5;
xdebug_debug_zval('r');
```

Hope it helps